# jQuery count div that has a display:none attribute

Tags: jquery, html, count

I want to count the div that has a class name "items" and has an attribute "style=display:none".

```
<div id="skills">
<div class="items" style="display:none">1</div>
<div class="items">2</div>
<div class="items">3</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">4</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">5</div></div>
```

the output should be '3'.

===========================================================

addition to the problem:

```
<div id="skills1">
<div class="items" style="display:none">1</div>
<div class="items">2</div>
<div class="items">3</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">4</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">5</div></div>

<div id="skills2">
<div class="items" style="display:none">1</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">2</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">3</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">4</div>
<div class="items" style="display:none">5</div></div>
```

the output should be '3' & '5'.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Original:

```
var count = $('div.items:hidden').length;
```

New:

```
var counts = {};
$('#skills1,#skills2').each( function() {
    counts[$(this).attr('id')] =  $('div.items:hidden', $(this)).length;
}
```

The `counts` object will be:

```
{ skills1 : 3, skills2 : 5 }
```

Last(?)

```
$('#skills1,#skills2').each( function() {
    if ($('div.items:hidden',$(this)).length == 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

It would be even easier if you gave the "containers" a class to use as a selector.  Then you could simply replace `#skills1,#skills2` with the class selector and not have the function be dependent on the names of the DIVs, meaning that it wouldn't have to change if you add another container, say `skills3`.  You'd just have to make sure to give that container the correct class.

Comment: thanks tvanfosson!..but i have a little bit complicated problem. how will i do this dynamically? pls. see the additional problem..thanks again in advance..

Comment: in your answer: 

var count = $('div.items:hidden').length;

if 'count' is equal to 0 and its parent id is 'skills1' then the div with the id 'skills1' will then display 'none'..

Comment: @scoohh -- you want to hide the DIV when the number of hidden elements contained in it is 0 or when the number of hidden items is equal to the number of items? Your last comment has me confused.

Comment: @scoohh -- I've added a solution for that as well.  As you're new, you'll want to remember to vote up helpful answers and accept the best answer (providing it's correct) by clicking the check mark next to the votes.